# Remove new line from result of system()

Tags: formatting, functions

I would like to store the result of a `system()` call in a variable without the trailing `^@` character. At the moment I do something like

```
var = system('command | xargs -i echo -n "{}"')
```

but it feels convoluted. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you don't want to use `systemlist` for whatever reason, you can explicitly remove the newline and/or whitespace.  Since vim 8.0.1630 (very recent), there is a `trim()` function which removes whitespace, including newline, from the *front and the back* of a string.

```
trim(system('command'))
```

A common way, if you know there will always be a trailing newline is:

```
system('command')[:-2]
```

Or, you can use substitute:

```
substitute(system('command'), '\n$', '', '')     " newline only
substitute(system('command'), '\_s*$', '', '')   " any whitespace
```

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware of `trim()`. It may do more than _chomp_ing the last newline though.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to use [`:h systemlist()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#systemlist%28%29):

> ```
> systemlist({expr} [, {input}])                *systemlist()*
>       Same as system(), but returns a List with lines (parts of
>       output separated by NL) with NULs transformed into NLs.
> ```

This is usally a good way to handle system call without having to handle the new line characters.